# malloc error when extending Python to call C++ function

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I am trying to wrap a C++ function to call from Python.
My C++ code compiles and runs successfully, but when I call it from python I get the following error:

```
python(6805,0x7fff78401300) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=8245930807582093312) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_alloc: std::bad_alloc
zsh: abort      python
```

Here is my C++ function, which crawls my filesystem:

```
const char * crawlDirectory(const string directory)
{
    std::vector<std::string> filesVector;
    std::vector<std::string> dirsVector;


    dirsVector.push_back(directory);

    int currDirectoryIndex = 0;

    while (currDirectoryIndex < dirsVector.size()) {
        GetFilesInDirectory(filesVector, dirsVector, dirsVector[currDirectoryIndex].c_str());
        currDirectoryIndex++;
    }


    std::string filesListString = "";
    for (int i=0; i<filesVector.size()-1; i++) {
        filesListString += filesVector[i].c_str() + SEPARATOR;
    }

    //add the last file path without the separator -- faster than a conditional for every iteration
    filesListString += filesVector[filesVector.size()-1].c_str();


    const char * retString = filesListString.c_str();


    return retString;
}
```

I don't think the problem is in 'GetFilesInDirectory()', but I will post it if necessary.

Here is the extern block, which helps me wrap the function:

```
extern "C" {
    Crawler* Crawler_new(){ return new Crawler(); }
    const char * Crawler_crawlDirectory(Crawler* crawler, const string directory){ return(crawler->crawlDirectory(directory)); }
}
```

Here is the python file that defines the Crawler class:

```
from ctypes import cdll
from ctypes import *

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./libcrawler.so')

lib.Crawler_crawlDirectory.restype = c_char_p
lib.Crawler_crawlDirectory.argtypes = [c_void_p, c_char_p]

lib.Crawler_new.restype = c_void_p

class Crawler(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = lib.Crawler_new()

    def crawlDirectory(self, path):
        return lib.Crawler_crawlDirectory(self.obj, path)
```

I am positive that my C++ code is being compiled correctly (with g++ as a dylib), because I have tested the wrapper with other functions that return simple things like char*s and integers, and they work correctly.

Here is how I am calling the function from python:

```
>>> from wrapper import *
>>> c = Crawler()
>>> files = c.crawlDirectory('/Users/whatever/desktop')
```

Can anyone give insight about solving this issue?

Edit: here is the problem report:

```
Process:               Python [7057]
Path:                  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:            Python
Version:               2.7.6 (2.7.6)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        zsh [390]
Responsible:           Terminal [285]
User ID:               501

PlugIn Path:             /Users/USER/Documents/*/libcrawler.so
PlugIn Identifier:       libcrawler.so
PlugIn Version:          ??? (0)

Date/Time:             2014-06-08 16:36:24.623 -0700
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10 (14A238x)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        F5B91E6D-C318-117A-A457-522AB46FF6DC

Sleep/Wake UUID:       E228A7B4-D89E-4DBF-ABF3-510F4CF0EC3B

Time Awake Since Boot: 29000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       8000 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
abort() called
terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_alloc: std::bad_alloc

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff90f5637a __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff88fcc5ff abort + 129
2   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff8b95fb31 abort_message + 257
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff8b9879b9 default_terminate_handler() + 243
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8849c522 _objc_terminate() + 124
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff8b9850a1 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff8b984b2c __cxa_throw + 121
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff8b98527a operator new(unsigned long) + 90
8   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00007fff94fd1f05 std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init(char const*, unsigned long) + 59
9   libcrawler.so                   0x000000010747cce0 Crawler_crawlDirectory + 32
10  libffi.dylib                    0x00007fff90eaaf44 ffi_call_unix64 + 76
11  libffi.dylib                    0x00007fff90eab781 ffi_call + 853
12  _ctypes.so                      0x0000000106d3c76e _ctypes_callproc + 874
13  _ctypes.so                      0x0000000106d36bb9 PyCData_set + 2386
14  org.python.python               0x00000001069f03b8 PyObject_Call + 99
15  org.python.python               0x0000000106a6cc23 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 11365
16  org.python.python               0x0000000106a7062a 0x1069e6000 + 566826
17  org.python.python               0x0000000106a6d406 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 13384
18  org.python.python               0x0000000106a69d8a PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1413
19  org.python.python               0x0000000106a697ff PyEval_EvalCode + 54
20  org.python.python               0x0000000106a897d1 0x1069e6000 + 669649
21  org.python.python               0x0000000106a895ed PyRun_InteractiveOneFlags + 353
22  org.python.python               0x0000000106a890fc PyRun_InteractiveLoopFlags + 192
23  org.python.python               0x0000000106a88fa6 PyRun_AnyFileExFlags + 60
24  org.python.python               0x0000000106a9ab0f Py_Main + 3051
25  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff8a5575c9 start + 1

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000006  rcx: 0x00007fff59221af8  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000d0f  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007fff59221b20  rsp: 0x00007fff59221af8
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x00007fff88ff6e80  r10: 0x0000000008000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x00007fff59221c80  r13: 0x00007fff592222e0  r14: 0x00007fff78401300  r15: 0x00007fff59221b60
  rip: 0x00007fff90f5637a  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x00007fff785f2fc8

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148
Trap Number:     133


Binary Images:
       0x1069dd000 -        0x1069ddfff  org.python.python (2.7.6 - 2.7.6) <4E825039-BF7C-36CC-95A6-2838E8CE9459> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
       0x1069e6000 -        0x106ad7fff  org.python.python (2.7.6 - 2.7.6) <CC202176-2054-3AFB-96FE-20A5BA7CDBB6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
       0x106c9b000 -        0x106cd9ff7 +readline.so (???) <91E41C1B-723F-375F-B456-45B90A19C9F6> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/readline-6.2.4.1-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg/readline.so
       0x106d34000 -        0x106d42fff  _ctypes.so (83) <BAFE040D-E6AE-3E23-A09F-263880D952DC> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
       0x106d4d000 -        0x106d50fff  _struct.so (83) <D7F99BC3-044F-36EF-BB24-8ABA131FFABB> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_struct.so
       0x106d57000 -        0x106d5aff7  math.so (83) <A4587FDC-4D30-3FC5-B69B-C83E8008F5BF> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/math.so
       0x106d60000 -        0x106e36fff +multiarray.so (0) <06018061-CCAB-3799-9DC3-1A519A7FD31C> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.0.dev_297f54b-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/numpy/core/multiarray.so
       0x106edf000 -        0x106ee8fff  datetime.so (83) <9C16F413-04EE-3A67-AB8A-0590C51A555C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.so
       0x106ef1000 -        0x106f32ff7 +umath.so (0) <EBCBAE97-82A7-3F13-8470-7118A54E7511> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.0.dev_297f54b-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/numpy/core/umath.so
       0x106f9f000 -        0x106fa1fff  _collections.so (83) <47D407DA-2ED6-32E6-AA28-2A82F6677A6F> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_collections.so
       0x106fa7000 -        0x106faafff  operator.so (83) <360151DB-EDA1-3AAA-ADCC-16F4B3B57B38> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/operator.so
       0x106fb0000 -        0x106fb4fff  itertools.so (83) <B4F4CA00-C7A9-30CD-A834-B2202E33D057> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/itertools.so
       0x106fbd000 -        0x106fbefff  _heapq.so (83) <F1606EC5-85A7-3D25-BD0F-6CD1089F18B8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_heapq.so
       0x106fc3000 -        0x106fcefff  cPickle.so (83) <38BE83AC-100C-31E5-B6BE-BFBA38F24AC4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/cPickle.so
       0x106fd4000 -        0x106fd5fff  cStringIO.so (83) <583550C2-A4BB-3038-8AE6-58D8C35CAB79> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/cStringIO.so
       0x106fda000 -        0x106fddff7 +_dotblas.so (0) <0D2C0BAC-0A7E-3324-BDBA-4E3C01FFD3CB> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.0.dev_297f54b-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/numpy/core/_dotblas.so
       0x107021000 -        0x107022fff  _functools.so (83) <C07D086C-63A9-32E0-9460-553B67CC9006> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_functools.so
       0x107026000 -        0x10703ffff +scalarmath.so (0) <207D4985-9B9D-353B-8419-A7A2FA6F6D3A> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.0.dev_297f54b-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/numpy/core/scalarmath.so
       0x107192000 -        0x107193fff  time.so (83) <39A9DB75-94B0-3D91-B970-ADE4E1B7BBAC> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/time.so
       0x1071da000 -        0x1071deff7 +_compiled_base.so (0) <CEF1E8DA-3736-39D9-AA2C-132F70776AB4> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.0.dev_297f54b-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/numpy/lib/_compiled_base.so
       0x1071e2000 -        0x1071e3fff +lapack_lite.so (0) <7CDD20D3-3903-3875-82D0-6177C0550787> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.0.dev_297f54b-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.so
       0x1071e7000 -        0x1071f2ff7 +_umath_linalg.so (0) <093CF1DC-B775-3078-AB5F-F4ABB3BCE778> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.0.dev_297f54b-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/numpy/linalg/_umath_linalg.so
       0x10723e000 -        0x10724dfff  _io.so (83) <B1E4FC21-3C8B-344C-AE56-177D85591782> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
       0x10725c000 -        0x10725cfff  grp.so (83) <10BFB045-A784-327B-9A1C-851884AF47B8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/grp.so
       0x107260000 -        0x107260fff  future_builtins.so (83) <93EF8852-740A-39D8-B2D1-3094593CCC8B> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/future_builtins.so
       0x1072a4000 -        0x1072abff7 +fftpack_lite.so (0) <2026A712-A912-32B2-9A66-A7AA0C5D1457> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.0.dev_297f54b-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/numpy/fft/fftpack_lite.so
       0x1072af000 -        0x1072b2fff  strop.so (83) <AE1A7549-6FB1-3D72-AEDE-9B5B25F144C3> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/strop.so
       0x1073b7000 -        0x1073f3fff +mtrand.so (0) <51712F8D-F79E-3166-AA9C-92518E35EF91> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.0.dev_297f54b-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/numpy/random/mtrand.so
       0x10747c000 -        0x107480fff +libcrawler.so (0) <4B56359C-6C37-3293-81AD-06588E1A8735> /Users/USER/Documents/*/libcrawler.so
    0x7fff6c79c000 -     0x7fff6c7d265f  dyld (352.2) <8C17275C-F355-3C22-B10F-ADA53C8AEBD9> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff8847d000 -     0x7fff88486fff  libsystem_pthread.dylib (96) <B5C91A1D-6806-32C3-80DA-5E09F1418E59> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x7fff88488000 -     0x7fff88489fff  libSystem.B.dylib (1212) <9461AF62-9273-3236-B9E6-FBAC96467BBC> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff8848b000 -     0x7fff8866f257  libobjc.A.dylib (642) <63DD3921-EDF7-30A5-9F65-6CA368E0B6F1> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7fff88f6f000 -     0x7fff88ffbfe7  libsystem_c.dylib (1041) <A34BCDEC-6C21-31C5-A233-BD36BD0A69D7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x7fff8958e000 -     0x7fff895c5ffb  libsystem_network.dylib (356) <30D3DC75-3499-3BD9-A089-2776C6381625> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
    0x7fff8961e000 -     0x7fff8964ef9f  libsystem_m.dylib (3083) <E791F535-7C94-3EC5-AE16-DD5B4E581228> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
    0x7fff896e2000 -     0x7fff896eafff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (557) <D5492C76-213A-39E5-AD06-55702A2EE270> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
    0x7fff89803000 -     0x7fff8981ffff  libsystem_malloc.dylib (51) <4CB1DDAA-16D4-3028-89C8-489B320C8FAA> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
    0x7fff8986b000 -     0x7fff8988ffff  libdispatch.dylib (416) <5FC03BF1-E013-3DA8-9106-1E9C5BD09053> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x7fff8a554000 -     0x7fff8a557ff7  libdyld.dylib (352.2) <58EDCF19-9F5E-3EBB-9F2F-6AAF4F29C3A7> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
    0x7fff8a571000 -     0x7fff8a572ffb  libremovefile.dylib (34) <223DA82A-6689-30EB-A8CD-8E06E9D80DFA> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x7fff8a66e000 -     0x7fff8a66efff  com.apple.Accelerate (1.10 - Accelerate 1.10) <0FAD7731-3711-3050-BF41-6D5FBBF782B1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
    0x7fff8a66f000 -     0x7fff8a671fff  libsystem_configuration.dylib (671) <EE252873-1698-31F7-9431-1CD4C954DA39> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
    0x7fff8a69b000 -     0x7fff8a6dfff7  libauto.dylib (186) <17AE377B-4C54-34E0-8545-22C36C51805B> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
    0x7fff8b72c000 -     0x7fff8b72dff7  libsystem_blocks.dylib (65) <E05B234F-8036-301B-B2F1-1D170F6D3D97> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
    0x7fff8b8d0000 -     0x7fff8b8dbfff  libcommonCrypto.dylib (60058) <655061E6-30D0-38AA-B50F-A87160E91A58> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
    0x7fff8b937000 -     0x7fff8b95efff  libxpc.dylib (496.0.0.0.4) <BA0E0D3B-7E92-3FD4-969B-8B30AF78314A> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
    0x7fff8b95f000 -     0x7fff8b98afff  libc++abi.dylib (125) <89FF241B-5BFB-330A-AA8B-931EBE9FDC3F> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
    0x7fff8b98b000 -     0x7fff8b98ffff  libcache.dylib (69) <69FA8935-1BDF-369C-8DA5-37F2E651FC1D> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
    0x7fff8bf3c000 -     0x7fff8bf3eff7  libsystem_coreservices.dylib (6) <CE029CE6-341E-316D-A63E-36018A87B630> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
    0x7fff8c7e8000 -     0x7fff8cbf5ff7  libLAPACK.dylib (1119) <6AAD6821-F578-382A-952A-BF47B13BE997> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
    0x7fff8d51b000 -     0x7fff8d632fef  libvDSP.dylib (497) <E14B640E-E093-3792-9944-720385AA833B> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib
    0x7fff8d976000 -     0x7fff8d97dff7  libcompiler_rt.dylib (35) <0F6AAF40-BCB9-3629-B6CD-4047D99B52F7> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
    0x7fff8d9c6000 -     0x7fff8dd5aff7  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 1132.15) <2595DDF9-31C2-3B2B-B8B7-E805F41FE73E> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff8ddd2000 -     0x7fff8dfb1ffb  libicucore.A.dylib (531.17) <4CD56103-046A-360B-A5BC-B81A103BBDBC> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x7fff8e4a4000 -     0x7fff8e4d4ff7  libncurses.5.4.dylib (44) <5092AA8D-0816-3EEF-B702-BEA98BF1E088> /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib
    0x7fff8e56e000 -     0x7fff8e572ff7  libsystem_stats.dylib (160.0.0.0.1) <44D7BDF8-C833-3F3B-85B6-C76ACDB81BC4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_stats.dylib
    0x7fff8ea25000 -     0x7fff8ea25ff7  libkeymgr.dylib (28) <552CCAE4-E242-3005-AB85-24C6E533D6E9> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
    0x7fff8f039000 -     0x7fff8f03bff7  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (344) <69ACEB2A-8DC9-3B89-8ECF-667AD6B485FC> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x7fff8f6af000 -     0x7fff8f6c4ff7  libsystem_asl.dylib (260) <3398113B-8429-3D3E-B728-E44205BAD4E2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
    0x7fff8fa82000 -     0x7fff8fa89ff7  libcopyfile.dylib (115) <802774AD-A71F-3A46-A7A9-810F8B8DA205> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
    0x7fff8fbae000 -     0x7fff8fc73fef  libvMisc.dylib (497) <658E4CC2-DA85-30A1-978E-5386DAA361E3> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
    0x7fff902c1000 -     0x7fff902d4ff7  libLinearAlgebra.dylib (1119) <F6A6D050-E257-3427-A05D-A46D2F4B57AB> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
    0x7fff90eaa000 -     0x7fff90eabfff  libffi.dylib (18.1) <BE2846BF-C1BA-3136-903F-A914CDBC7328> /usr/lib/libffi.dylib
    0x7fff90f40000 -     0x7fff90f5dfff  libsystem_kernel.dylib (2738.0.0.0.5) <07664A85-DF08-3113-8817-B726F7774B14> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7fff9106e000 -     0x7fff910e3fff  libcorecrypto.dylib (211.0.0.0.1) <6D9E2007-EF3B-3665-AA15-A356090540B6> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
    0x7fff9162d000 -     0x7fff91632fff  libsystem_networkextension.dylib (112) <4C3B20D2-18FB-35BE-A695-8E56BAC1D3A8> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
    0x7fff91638000 -     0x7fff91638fff  com.apple.Accelerate.vecLib (3.10 - vecLib 3.10) <1AEEC774-2F65-3763-B52E-C04C0DD05F63> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
    0x7fff918e2000 -     0x7fff918e7ff7  libunwind.dylib (35.3) <4BD86D0A-A203-3FEB-BFED-5668B180AB49> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
    0x7fff93093000 -     0x7fff93099fff  libsystem_trace.dylib (47.0.0.0.2) <3496EA08-6D61-37F0-A557-8AD734F0480E> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
    0x7fff93945000 -     0x7fff93946fff  libunc.dylib (28) <43600429-64D7-3578-ACCE-7642190EE835> /usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib
    0x7fff93947000 -     0x7fff9394ffff  libsystem_platform.dylib (61) <90DD0380-D3ED-346A-B4A8-1F1D11D42032> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
    0x7fff93952000 -     0x7fff9395bffb  libsystem_notify.dylib (129) <7F8F5086-AD7A-3C80-BBCB-AD54EA44376B> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
    0x7fff94168000 -     0x7fff945bafef  com.apple.vImage (8.0 - 8.0) <ACD86E88-A9F7-3E95-BA51-4208E2D879B8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
    0x7fff9469e000 -     0x7fff946a0ff7  libquarantine.dylib (73) <EE50CAE5-1596-3344-8760-579EFAF176F2> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
    0x7fff94f92000 -     0x7fff94fe6fff  libc++.1.dylib (120) <C6EFD658-B948-36F4-905D-A9780797D0D1> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    0x7fff9556f000 -     0x7fff95580fff  libsystem_coretls.dylib (29) <B95FEAC8-6C16-382A-BE5C-5B34F6A4E8FD> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib
    0x7fff9574c000 -     0x7fff958d9fff  libBLAS.dylib (1119) <93F54197-FEA7-31A1-B960-CCD78F87702E> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
    0x7fff95ce4000 -     0x7fff95ce4ff7  liblaunch.dylib (496.0.0.0.4) <25D0EE80-85D2-379D-BF76-09B417C0FD19> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
    0x7fff95d83000 -     0x7fff95d88ff7  libmacho.dylib (861) <BF14A7C8-2711-38E7-B05E-6AE66D5323CA> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
    0x7fff961f6000 -     0x7fff96207ff7  libz.1.dylib (55) <68DE8C8A-0320-3269-AABF-D26D73F50001> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x7fff96564000 -     0x7fff96565fff  libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib (100) <9F8277CE-07E0-39CD-A2EE-581D02EBE58B> /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
    0x7fff96672000 -     0x7fff9669aff3  libsystem_info.dylib (456) <E997A3CF-82FE-36F5-B246-3E73C98BEE02> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
    0x7fff96a65000 -     0x7fff96a66fff  libsystem_secinit.dylib (16) <F2CA96CB-D627-3407-830C-E2E1D48E457B> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_secinit.dylib

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 203216
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 493

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=100.7M resident=15.8M(16%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=85.0M(84%)
Writable regions: Total=31.9M written=8868K(27%) resident=11.9M(37%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=20.0M(63%)

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
Kernel Alloc Once                     4K
MALLOC                             23.3M
MALLOC (admin)                       16K
STACK GUARD                        56.0M
Stack                              8192K
VM_ALLOCATE                          16K
__DATA                             2080K
__LINKEDIT                         74.3M
__TEXT                             26.4M
__UNICODE                           544K
shared memory                         4K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             190.7M

Model: MacBookPro5,4, BootROM MBP53.00AC.B03, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.53 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.49f2
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, PCI, 256 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x857F, 0x483634353155363446373036364700000000
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x857F, 0x483634353155363446373036364700000000
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x8D), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.24)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.0d49 14130, 3 services, 24 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: Samsung SSD 840 EVO 750GB, 750.16 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-868
USB Device: Built-in iSight
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Edit: Stack trace from gdb:
http://pastebin.com/ncx5fTRg
(reached SO question size limit).

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you'd expect an allocation of 8 zettabytes to fail.

Comment: @Adam Of course, but how can I rewrite this code so that it will work when called from Python?

Comment: @fonZ the argument to `mach_vm_map`.

Comment: @Adam looks more like 8 Exabytes

Comment: But I would appreciate a helpful answer :)

Comment: you are correct, I miscounted :P. That said the only really wrong thing that jumps out at me is `filesVector[filesVector.size()-1]`. You're assuming `filesVector` is not empty. But I'd expect that to result in a segfault.

Comment: It's unclear whether or not the problem is present in the code you posted. It is clear that you need to do more legwork to narrow down where the error comes from. I expect that to be easy. Just run it through the debugger and it should at least give you a stack trace that should point the problem out. `gdb python` `set args myscript.py` `run`

Comment: @Adam I have added the stack trace from gdb -- the problem is still unclear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55292/discussion-between-yoni201-and-adam).

Comment: You haven't posted anything that would assist in diagnosing the problem. You're getting an error from malloc. Where are you calling malloc? If you can't tell us that, you're on your own. You'll need to use gdb or ddd to find out. The "back trace" you posted doesn't contain a backtrace (produced by typing 'bt' in gdb). Maybe you should start by calling your code from C++ rather than Python. But why don't you just use pythons `os.walk()`?

Comment: You aren't passing a `const string` to `Crawler_crawlDirectory`. It's a `char *`, so change the parameter declaration to `const char *directory` and update the function to create a `string`. Also, don't leave C++ exceptions unhandled in a C API.

Comment: @kfsone os.walk() is slower than my implemented solution. I've tested this multiple times.